# How to visualize a Markov chain in the following way?

Tags: probability, markov-chains, visualization

Nice to meet you, this is my first question in this site.

I now can draw $A\to B\to C$ but stuck at $A\to B\to C\to D$. Let me show you my graph: [$A\to B\to C$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqJkU.png).

It's easy to see that $A$, $B$ and $C$ are not independent to each other, but conditional on $B$, then $A$ and $C$ would be independent, which can deduce the Markov property: $P(C|B,A)=P(C|B)$.

So, how to draw $A\to B\to C\to D$ in a similar way, or more generally, draw $X_1\to X_2\to \dots\to X_n$? Or is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer by myself:

[image]

And here is $X_1\to X_2\to\dots\to X_{10}$:

[image]